# Error building image: Error building rlang - not available on R 3.5.0 (Uploading shiny)

Tags: r, shiny

I have updated my `R` to the version `3.5.0` because of all the good things I have heard about it. Actually everything is OK until now. The problem is that I am trying to upload my shiny dashboard to shinyapps.io and I'm getting the following error:

```
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 334227...DONE
Deploying bundle: 1353909 for application: 334227 ...
Waiting for task: 523743840
  building: Building image: 1366625
  building: Building package: rlang
################################ Begin Task Log ################################ 
################################# End Task Log ################################# 
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 523743841 failed: Error building image: Error building rlang (0.2.0.9001). R version 3.5.0 currently unavailable
Execution halted
```

Any ideas how can I get rid of this problem? Is it a bug? I am using the `library(shinydashboard)`version `0.7.0` based on `library(shiny)` version `1.0.5` for the dashboard.

Thanks and hope you can help me! :)

Comment: Did you re-compile your libraries with `R 3.5.0`? If not, you need to run `update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE, ask = FALSE, repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com")`

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mr @Tung but yes I re-compiled all my libraries with the update. Actually, re-ran your command and still having the same error.. any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed it is a universal problem. Seems as "It typically takes about a day after the Ubuntu R packages are built and available on CRAN for shinyapps.io 2 to support a new version of R" (from https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-deploying-to-shinyapps-io/7899/5)

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be taking a few days before shiny adapts the new updates. In the meantime, you can upload your shinyapp by changing the version of R you are using back to the last update.

This can be done by going to
Tools>Global Options>R Version:

Press change, and select an earlier version of R. Restart R-studio and upload should work :)