# Deploy R app in shinyapps.io - “Error Unhandled Exception"

Tags: r, deploying

I'm trying to deploy my first app in shinyapps.io through RStudio but I can't. The console prompts this:

> Preparing to deploy application...DONE
>   Uploading bundle for application: 337344...DONE
>   Deploying bundle: 1355635 for application: 337344 ...
>   Waiting for task: 523919702
>     building: Processing bundle: 1355635
>      building: Building image: 1368415
>      error: Building package: rlang
>
> ########################## Begin Task Log ################################
>   
>   ########################### End Task Log #################################
>
> Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 523919707 failed: Error building image:   Error building rlang (0.2.0). R version 3.5.0 currently unavailable
>   Ejecuci�n interrumpida

Any suggestion to solve this problem...?
I've tried everything and I don't want to revert to the previous R version, in case this was the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same question here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50158781/error-building-image-error-building-rlang-not-available-on-r-3-5-0-uploading

Answer (score 1):

For now, downgrade to R 3.4.4 would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly it seems to be a problem with R 3.5. Shinyapps.io currently doesn't support this version. Probably you would go for a downgrade or wait until it gets the needed support.

I've found the same problem here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-deploying-to-shinyapps-io/7899

Cheers from Brazil.